# A swiftUI problem: troubles on applying state property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a reminder using SwiftUI, which requires a timer.

My problem is, the time variables, including hour, minute, and second, could not update on the GUI because of the absence of a State variable.

While in my case, I don't know how to translate the binding variable `times`, which firstly go through the method ensure it is a two-digit String, to a State variable. The body variable doesn't allow me to do it inside, and I could not use the binding variable and function outside either. What should I do?

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresentView: View {
    @Binding var times: DataStorage
    @State private var hourOut = "" // Stuck at here
    @State private var AlertPresent = false
    @State private var timerRun = false
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    func DigitPresent(time: Int) -> String {
        guard time > 9 else {
            return "0\(String(time))"
        }
        return String(time)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(DigitPresent(time: times.hour)) : \(DigitPresent(time: times.minute)) : \(DigitPresent(time: times.second))")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                    if (timerRun == true) {
                        if (times.second > 0) {
                            times.second -= 1
                        } else if (times.minute > 0) {
                            times.minute += 59
                            times.minute -= 1
                        } else if (times.hour > 0) {
                            times.minute += 59
                            times.second += 59
                            times.hour -= 1
                        } else {
                            AlertPresent = true
                            timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                        }
                    }
                })
                .alert(isPresented: $AlertPresent, content: {
                    Alert(title: Text("Time over"), message: nil, dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
                        AlertPresent = false
                    }))
                })
            Button(action: {
                timerRun = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Start/Stop")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct PresentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PresentView(times: .constant(DataStorage.data[0]))
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to apply EnvironmentObject into this view. While the problem is, there are other views using binding property variable using a NavigationView links to this View, which cause an error of false datatype:

```
struct SetView: View {
    @Binding var cards: [DataStorage]
    @State private var sheetPresent = false
    @State private var newReminder = DataStorage.dataOutput()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (cards) { card in
                NavigationLink(destination: PresentView(times: connect(to: card))) {
                    CardView(info: card)
                }
                .listRowBackground(card.color)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("information")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            sheetPresent = true
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }))
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresent, content: {
            NavigationView {
                EditView(storedData: $newReminder)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Delete", action: {
                        sheetPresent = false
                    }), trailing: Button("Add", action: {
                        let information = DataStorage(title: newReminder.title, hour: newReminder.hour, minute: newReminder.minute, second: newReminder.second, color: newReminder.color)
                        cards.append(information)
                        sheetPresent = false
                }))
            }
        })
    }
    private func connect (to card: DataStorage) -> EnvironmentObject<DataStorage> {
        guard let cardNumber = cards.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == card.id}) else {
                fatalError("Can't find card")
        }
        return $cards[cardNumber] // The error starts here
    }
}
```

What should I do? To fix the connect function or change the "card" variable's property?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your DataStorage variable, but I would say make it a class that conforms to @ObservableObject, and then apply @Published to hour, minute, second.

Then declare times as @ObservedObject rather than @Binding .

I would also move the logic that you have in your onReceive into the DataStorage - your view should only be concerned with telling it to update, not how.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I also tried to move onReceive to DataStorage, while could not find a position to place. I will focus on it later, because another problem's raised: there is another view has a NavigationLink to the PresentView, which make an error about false datatype. I've updated my question. please take a look at it if you feel convenient.

Comment: You can't have onReceive in your DataStorage, leave the onReceive on your view, but it can just call the function in DataStorage containing the logic to update the hour, minute, second vars.